# How to set color theme in TeXShop?

Tags: editors, texshop

This seems incredibly basic and I can't believe I have to ask this, but *how do I activate a color theme in TeXShop*? I can find the section of Preferences for *editing* the themes, but I can't find any way to tell TeXShop which theme I want to use! Nor does Googling get me anywhere, except changelogs that explain all the nice features related to color themes.

Thanks...

Comment: Choose a theme, and when you click at "OK" at the bottom, the preference window is closed and the choosed theme is in effect (version 4.27).

Comment: When you say "choose a theme," which dropdown are you referring to? In the "Lite Mode Theme" dropdown, I can choose "DarkTheme", and when I close, the dark theme is indeed activated. But that's basically saying, I want my light mode theme to be "DarkTheme". Isn't there a way to say, I want to use my dark mode theme?

Comment: I'm under High Sierra, in fact I don't understand why the TeXShop Preferences displays a "Dark mode", isn't it reserved for Mojave and above? Are you under Mojave?

Comment: I'm in High Sierra too. So are you saying Dark Mode is a system-level (not application-level) preference?

Comment: In El Capitan, Dark Mode is *not* a system-level preference (just "use dark menu bar and Dock"). For me, the workaround is what @quark67 suggested---which is, indeed, the same as saying "I want my light mode theme to be DarkTheme." Not perfect (in a perfect world I'd be using a more modern OS!), but works.

Comment: Same question here. I searched around and all I read is telling you to go to Preference then click OK somewhere to set the them.  But no I couldn't find anywhere to set a dark mode.