# How to change to Dark Mode in TexShop?

Tags: texshop

I've googled as hard as I can but finding no answers. Any result I searched for seems to suggest there's a place where I can just click to have the theme changed:

```
Open TeXShop and go to Preferences > Themes
Select the theme from the Themes drop down menus and press OK
```

- [TeXShop-Themes](https://github.com/monikajaskolka/TeXShop-Themes)
- [SE: TeXShop GUI in Dark Mode hard to read](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549997/texshop-gui-in-dark-mode-hard-to-read)
- [Reddit: TeXShop Dark Theme in TexWorks?](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/y86d4f/comment/it07xlp/)

There is a similar if not identical question on SE left unanswered for years:

[SE: How to set color theme in TexShop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490731/how-to-set-color-theme-in-texshop)

I tried various combination of selecting an item in drop down, changing the color in the palette, and clicking in Preference > Themes.  Yet I can't change TexShop to Dark Mode or refresh it to any other theme.

[image]

Comment: Changing themes works for me (TeXShop 5.03 on Catalina 10.15.7). "Dark Mode Theme" refers to the theme to use when macOS is in Dark Mode, which must be enabled at the top of your Mac's System Preferences -> General window. However, I'm running Catalina in Light Mode and I'm still able to set my "Lite Mode Theme" to PreTeXt-Dark and it works fine.

Comment: Dark/Light Mode are set in System Preferences on  a user by user basis. If you just wish a Dark Mode Theme in TeXShop but want Light Mode for everything simply choose one of the Dark Mode Theme as a Lite Mode Theme and Save it (i.e., click OK). Youcan then edit that Theme to yourn liking.

Comment: @HerbSchulz thanks. Not sure why I stumble on that for hours but haven't thought of putting the Dark Mode under Lite Mode Theme.